# Amazon Redshift return name of day

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to get the name of the day of a specific date. 
For example for the date "11/22/2019" I want the result to be "Friday"

I use Amazon Redshift.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `to_char()`:

```
select to_char(datecol, 'Day')
```

Note that this value is padded to 9 characters, so for most weekdays, it will end in a bunch of spaces.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid empty space in the output of 'select to_char(current_date, 'Day');' and to get the exact day name you can use the below query.

select trim(' ' FROM to_char(current_date, 'Day'));